# block inside interpolation with ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, codeblocks, string-interpolation

I'm writing a simple program that asks the user for input for an array and spits out the array and its average. Really easy and I had no issues with it.

In the end I came up with: (in this example I'll just use a random array instead of the code for the user input)

```
array = [1,2,3]
sum = array.inject(:+)
average = sum.to_f/array.length
puts "The numbers you entered in the array were: #{array.join(" ")}"
puts "The average of those numbers are: #{average}"
```

The output is expected and gives me:

```
The numbers you entered in the array were: 1 2 3
The averages of those numbers are: 2.0
```

However, when I was first trying to code this I was trying to be real slick for an easy assignment and I tried doing an interpolation inside of an interpolation. I utilized this code:

For the fourth line in the above code I used:

```
puts "The numbers you entered in the array were: #{array.each{|num| print "#{num} "}}"
```

which outputted:

```
1 2 3 The numbers you entered in the array were: [1, 2, 3]
```

So I thought there might have been an issue with doing an interpolation inside a block that was inside of an interpolation.
So I then ran the following code to test for just a block inside interpolation.

```
puts "The numbers you entered in the array were: #{array.each{|num| print num}}"
```

which outputted:

```
123The numbers you entered in the array were: [1, 2, 3]
```

Can anyone explain the me why the proc is executed inside of the interpolation first, printed and then the puts happens. In addition, why did it puts the array in array.inspect form when I never called .inspect on the array.

Comment: Use `map`, not `each`. And get rid of `print`, its side effect is printing to stdout. It is useless for what you're trying to do.

Comment: I understand how to get the result I want, I'm trying to figure out why the code did what it did. What exactly is the side effect to printing to stdout? I'm pretty new to programming. SO I'm not entirely sure even what stdout is.

Comment: I think I just answered one part of my question after fiddling with IRB. I guess when you interpolate an array in a string it puts in the inspect form of the array

Comment: I think we are all hung up on the Array "bug" when Andrew is really asking us about why 123 shows up in front.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The question you want answered

When you use variable interpolation, that value to interpolate is going to resolve before the original string.

In this case, your Array.each is doing it's thing and printing out "1" then "2" and finally "3". It returns the original Array of [1, 2, 3]

```
output> 123 # note new line because we used print
```

Now that your interpolation is resolved, the rest of the puts finishes up and uses the returned value of [1, 2, 3] and prints:

```
output> The numbers you entered in the array were: [1, 2, 3]\n
```

To get the final output of:

```
output> 123The numbers you entered in the array were: [1, 2, 3]\n
```

### The question everyone WANTS to answer :)

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Array.html#method-i-each

When calling Array.each with a block, the return is self.

This is "bad" in your case, because you don't want self returned. It will always return the same thing, your original array.

```
puts "The numbers you entered in the array were: #{array.each{|num| num*2}}"
The numbers you entered in the array were: [1, 2, 3] # WAT?
```

As a Sergio Tulentsev said, use .map and .join

```
puts "The numbers you entered in the array were: #{array.map{|num| num*2}.join(' ')}"
The numbers you entered in the array were: 2 4 6
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying; however, it still doesn't answer my question as to why what happens in the proc in my example happens before the puts statement. I think Sergio was trying to explain with the side effect to stdout, but I'm not entirely sure what that means.

Comment: I imagine that because the return value of the array.each is just the array. It still wants to run the print block? and it just shoves it in front of the puts?

Comment: I think you may be confusing yourself. You aren't using any procs. Every call you have returns a value immediately. What is happening is that each print/puts is printing out it's value as soon as it finishes. So in your case, those inside of your Array.each block finish first and print out to start the line, and then your puts finishes after the each block has finished. Yielding your "123The numbers you entered in the array were: [1, 2, 3]"

Comment: I see because interpolation uses the return value of the each method which is just the original array. It still runs the print num block and just prints the numbers in the array then the puts happens..

Comment: @AndrewKim: RE "side effect": when a function returns a value that depends solely on its arguments (and doesn't cause anything else to happen), it is called a "pure function". `print`, `puts` and their kin are the opposite of pure - they return nothing and they cause things to happen (some symbols appear in your console). This is what's called "side effect" (external world changes when function is executed)